# How can I install online-todos application?

Tags: meteor

Please check if you can install this.
https://github.com/AjayMT/online-todos 
I have an error with relase file meteor.
Please give me some step to install this app.

Answer (score 1):

The last commit on that repo was 2 years ago, which is a lifetime in Meteor terms, so this is going to use a version of meteor which is way, way out of date.  It would probably take a lot of work to get it to function with a supported version.

Whether you're looking for this as a way to learn Meteor or for something to actually use, you should be using the [official todos app](https://www.meteor.com/try/12).  The (correct) instructions for Meteor installation are [here](https://www.meteor.com/install).